# Azure Active Directory - Single Tenant App Login Issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When I try to access the 'About' page using 'Employee' role user whose Directory role is set to 'Global Administrator', I am able to access the page whereas when Directory role is set to 'User' for that user, I am not able to access the page and receiving error as *'This application requires application permissions to another application. Consent for application permissions can only be performed by an administrator.'*

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Employee")]
 public ActionResult About()
 {
 ViewBag.Message = "Only Employee can access this page.";
 return View();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app seems has the permissions which need to be consented by admin . If you are the tenant admin, you can consent for all users through admin consent. To do admin consent:

1 .Navigate to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/) and go to App Registrations. Inside your app's blade, hit Grant Permissions.
[image]

2 .construct a  OAuth2/OpenID Connect authorization request with &prompt=admin_consent.

Comment: Any update ? If you have further problem, please let me known.